# How do I optimize a MySQL Query which uses a function to parse JSON data

Tags: mysql, performance, view, mysql-json

I have an `Analytics` table that has the following structure:

```
+---------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+-------+
| user_id | label_id | application_id | session_id | date                | score |
+---------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+-------+
|       1 |      123 |              1 | ABCD123456 | 2023-06-15 09:05:18 |   123 |
|       1 |      456 |              1 | ABCD123456 | 2023-06-15 09:05:18 |   456 |
|       1 |      789 |              1 | ABCD123456 | 2023-06-15 09:05:18 |   789 |
+---------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

The `score` column type is always `varchar` but mid-way through development, the developers of the front-end decided it would be a good idea to save `JSON` data in this column (despite my better judgement).

As I am primarily working on backend systems, reporting, analytics and stuff, I tend to work with a lot of avearges, sums etc. I created a `materialized view` (essentially a table with triggers in my case) which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE WeldingSessionsAgregated AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT session_id as s_id,
    user_id,
    date,
    application_id,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 125 AND session_id = s_id) AS session_start,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 126 AND session_id = s_id) AS session_end,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 129 AND session_id = s_id) AS part_name,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 132 AND session_id = s_id) AS displacement_map,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 133 AND session_id = s_id) AS weld_preview,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 135 AND session_id = s_id) AS method,
    (SELECT score FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 136 AND session_id = s_id) AS material_used,
    (SELECT organization_id FROM Users WHERE Users.id = user_id) AS organization_id,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "speedEntries") AS speed_sum) AS speed_sum,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "travelAngleEntries") AS travel_angle_sum) AS travel_angle_sum,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "workAngleEntries") AS work_angle_sum) AS work_angle_sum,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "distanceEntries") AS distance_sum) AS distance_sum,
    (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(score, '$.speedEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = s_id) AS count,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "speedEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(score, '$.speedEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = s_id) + 0.00001) AS avg_speed,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "travelAngleEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(score, '$.travelAngleEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = s_id) + 0.00001) AS avg_travel_angle,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "workAngleEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(score, '$.workAngleEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = s_id) + 0.00001) AS avg_work_angle,
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "distanceEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(score, '$.distanceEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = s_id) + 0.00001) AS avg_distance
  FROM Analytics WHERE application_id = 7;
```

The function definition for `get_welding_array_sum` is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_welding_array_sum(sid VARCHAR(256), array_name VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE numEntries, i INT;
    SELECT JSON_LENGTH(score, CONCAT('$.', array_name)) INTO numEntries FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = sid;
    
    SET i = 0;
    SET result = 0.0;

    WHILE i < numEntries DO
        SET result = result + (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(score, CONCAT('$.', array_name, '[', i, ']')) FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = sid);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN result;
END;
```

And here is the `trigger` that handles the insert to `WeldingSessionsAgregated` before insert on `Analytics`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER WeldingSessionsAgregatedInsertTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Analytics
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE num INT;
    DECLARE is_sealing INT;
    IF NEW.application_id = 7 THEN
        SET is_sealing = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 134 AND session_id = NEW.session_id AND score = "sealing");
        if is_sealing > 0 THEN DELETE FROM WeldingSessionsAgregated WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id;
        ELSE 
            SET num = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WeldingSessionsAgregated WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id);
            if num = 0 THEN 
                INSERT INTO WeldingSessionsAgregated (
                    s_id,
                    user_id,
                    date,
                    application_id,
                    organization_id
                ) VALUES (
                    NEW.session_id,
                    NEW.user_id,
                    NEW.date,
                    NEW.application_id,
                    (SELECT organization_id FROM Users WHERE id = NEW.user_id)
                );
            END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 125 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET session_start = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 126 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET session_end = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 129 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET part_name = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 132 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET displacement_map = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 133 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET weld_preview = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 135 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET method = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 136 THEN UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET material_used = NEW.score WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id; END IF;
            IF NEW.label_id = 127 THEN
                UPDATE WeldingSessionsAgregated SET
                    speed_sum = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "speedEntries")),
                    travel_angle_sum = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "travelAngleEntries")),
                    work_angle_sum = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "workAngleEntries")),
                    distance_sum = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "distanceEntries")),
                    count = (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(NEW.score, '$.speedEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = NEW.session_id),
                    avg_speed = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "speedEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(NEW.score, '$.speedEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = NEW.session_id) + 0.00001),
                    avg_travel_angle = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "travelAngleEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(NEW.score, '$.travelAngleEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = NEW.session_id) + 0.00001),
                    avg_work_angle = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "workAngleEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(NEW.score, '$.workAngleEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = NEW.session_id) + 0.00001),
                    avg_distance = (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(NEW.session_id, "distanceEntries")) / ((SELECT JSON_LENGTH(NEW.score, '$.distanceEntries') FROM Analytics WHERE label_id = 127 AND session_id = NEW.session_id) + 0.00001)
                    WHERE s_id = NEW.session_id;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END; //
```

As you can see, all this is just basic standard stuff one would use in order to re-structure the data in order to reduce the amount of calculation and save time on report generation. The report generation drastically decreased (upwards of factor of 10) but now the issue is that the insertion into the WeldingSessionsAgregated is extremely taxing when inserting multiple sessions at once.

I had to add a new column into the `WeldingSessionsAgregated` and I figured why write an alter table query when I can just drop the table and re-generate it. I did that before writing this question and I am still waiting for it to execute on like 150 sessions (I checked the CPU and it seens ti be struggling at 100%). My primary concern is that this has not yet been tested under high capacity. If I have 100+ users using the application and they all start sending in sessions, the CPU might just go to 100% and start throttling performance which is crucial in my case.

Just by looking at my code, can anyone provide me with any way to make my code more efficient? I am by no means a MySQL wizard, so I am pretty much sure that somebody will find something to improve here.

Edit: Adding create table for `Analytics`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Analytics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `score` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `label_id` (`label_id`),
  KEY `application_id` (`application_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Analytics_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Analytics_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`label_id`) REFERENCES `AnalyticLabels` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Analytics_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) REFERENCES `Applications` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35835 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE Analytics` -- It is very likely that the `PRIMARY KEY` is inadequate.
- Don't use a `SELECT` when an expression would do:

  ```
    (SELECT get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "speedEntries") AS speed_sum) AS speed_sum,
  ```

  ==>

  ```
    get_welding_array_sum(s_id, "speedEntries") AS speed_sum,
  ```
- It looks like there are 4 subqueries for `label_id = 127`, try to use one `JOIN` and then 4 expressions.

(I may have more tips later.)

Comment: I have updated my view accoardingly but I did not see a significant improvement in performance. The most crucial thing I think is the `JSON` parsing which tends to take a lot of time (parsing large JSON object four times). I think it would make sense to parse it once and somehow store the results but I am not sure how I'd do that, if you know that'd be great. I tried asking ChatGPT but it didnt provide a good answer so I am still not sure if it is possible.

Comment: @Dimitar - Any fields you need to search on (`WHERE`) or sort by (`ORDER BY`) should be put into table columns so that the code does not need to do laboriously extract them from JSON.  Furthermore, this will allow you to use `INDEXes` to further speed up queries.

Comment: Copy the data to the new columns as you insert new rows.